# Why were so many currently successful football (soccer) teams founded around the year 1900?

Tags: europe, sports

e.g. Manchester United, Real Madrid, Juventus, Bayern München.

Comment: Because the modern age of professional sports began around 1900. By definition, *successful* clubs tend to be long-lasting, hence are still around 11 decades later.